# Distance of two geo point android

Tags: android-mapview, android-manifest

I am new android application developer. I have create a mapview application where i need to calculate the distance of two geo point.How can i do that.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) method:

```
GeoPoint prev, current;
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(prev.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, prev.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, current.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, current.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, results);
```